# "Linear Model" of a Pendulum via Euler's Method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

In my problem the linear modal is defined as the first term in the series expansion of sin(x) so:

[image]

sin(x) = x is the linear modal.

So with this, I then have to write

[image]

as a system of x' and y', so:

[image]

I tried the linear modal in Euler's method, with initial conditions X(1) = 1  and V(1)=0 (V would be y then following the last equations):

```
for i = 1:1000
    V(i+1) = V(i)-(1.*s) ;
    X(i+1) = V(i);
end
```

Where s is the step size. But apparently I'm supposed to get a circle when I plot V with respect to X which makes sense, but all I get is a straight line.

If I change it to:

```
for i = 1:1000
    V(i+1) = V(i)-(X(i).*s) ;
    X(i+1) = V(i);
end
```

With s=0.8 I get a spiral, which looks like a development but I'm no closer to the circular shape that I am expecting. I think I just need a fresh pair of eyes to see where perhaps an obvious error lies.

Answer (score 2):

You are coding something drastically different than you wrote down in the equations. If you wrote down the equations with the same order and variable names, you would probably already see your error.

Also, the following things should have tipped you off:

- The step size does not appear as a linear factor in both equations.
- In your first attempt, `X` has no impact on `V`.

Nonetheless, here is a direct translation of your equations to code (and the Euler method):

```
for i = 1:1000
    x(i+1) = x(i) + y(i)*s;
    y(i+1) = y(i) + sin(x(i))*s;
end
```

If you really want to use the linear approximation, just replace `sin(x(i))` by `x(i)`. However, the main point of the linear approximation is that it’s nice for analytical solutions and theoretical analysis. Since you are solving the problem numerically, I do not see a need for it.

Finally, note that since you are integrating a Hamiltonian system, you will very quickly see the problems of the Euler method, i.e., you will always get a blatant spiral. Just imagine what would happen if you simulate the motion of the earth around the sun with tangential vectors:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer. However, is Euler's method not of form y(i+1) = y(i) + s*y'(i) ? Why did you just multiply s? Also if I plot the code you wrote with y with respect to x I do not get the circle which I need.

Comment: *Why did you just multiply s?* – Argh; my fault; fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't also the fact that sin(x) is negative in my original problem factor into the Euler's method? Why wouldn't it be cos(x) too, since it's s*y'(i) ?

Comment: The circular nature I'm talking about is sort of resembled in my semi-linear modal (first two terms of the series): http://pasteboard.co/s5xbGhYbP.png . The smaller step sizes tend to spiral off and lose the circular form. I was under the impression that the linear modal would be close to a perfect circle

Comment: *Wouldn't also the fact that sin(x) is negative in my original problem factor into the Euler's method?* – Yes, it should be `-sin(x)`, but that’s a mistake you already made when deriving the differential equations (it’s already [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mjtI.gif)).

Comment: *Why wouldn't it be cos(x) too, since it's s*y'(i) ?* – If I am understanding this correctly, you want to make use of the fact that `y(i)=sin(x)`, but that’s already the analytical solution, which you would not typically know at this stage.